# How to store access log of squid proxy 3.5 in mysql database on ubuntu server 16.04 LTS

Tags: squid

How can I store access log of squid proxy server 3.5 in mysql database. This setup runs on Ubuntu Server 16.04

Comment: If i am not wrong, squid has logging module for storing access log in MySQL by just do some easy configuration. The module name is log_db_daemon and maybe you can see this tutorial (i don't think it directly answer your question, because the tutorial was done using CentOs) [http://blog.aryyadwisatya.com/2017/01/storing-squid-log-in-mysql-using.html](http://blog.aryyadwisatya.com/2017/01/storing-squid-log-in-mysql-using.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/paranormal/blooper
I'm using that currently to put access into postgresql and works great.